# CakePHP2での複数ファイルのアップロードをしたい

Tags: cakephp

お世話になります。

CakePHP2で画像のアップロード掲示板を作成していますが
複数ファイルアップロードについてどうすればできるのか悩んでいます。

※CakePHPの本も複数読んでいますが、複数ファイルをアップロードしたものがありません

--やったこと

まず最初に以下のような投稿フォームを作ろうとしました。
・タイトル(text)
・記事(textarea)
・画像１(file)
・画像２(file)
・画像３(file)
・画像４(file)

そのため、まず下記の２つのテーブルを作成しました。

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `del_flg` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Viewには下記のように書きました。

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('type' => 'file', 'action' => 'done')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'text')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'textarea')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Post.Image.0.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Post.Image.1.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Post.Image.2.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Post.Image.3.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('description'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('Post.Image.0.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('Post.Image.1.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('Post.Image.2.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->error('Post.Image.3.image'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('投稿する'); ?>
```

次にPostモデルと、Imageモデルを作りました。

--Post

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array("Image");
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'maxLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 30),
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
            ),
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'maxLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 150),
                'required' => true,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
?>
```

-- Image

```
<?php
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Post');
    public $validate = array(
        'image' => array(
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'extension' => array(
                'rule' => array('extension', array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')),
                'message' => '有効な画像ファイルを指定してください。',
            ),
            'fileSize' => array(
                'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '2MB'),
                'message' => '画像は 2MB 未満でなければなりません。'
            ),
            'uploadError' => array(
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => 'ファイルアップロードで障害が起こりました。',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
?>
```

-- PostsController

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function done() {
        $user_id = $this->Auth->user("id");
        $this->Post->set('user_id', $user_id);
        if (!empty($this->request->data['id'])) {
            // 追加
            $this->Post->id = $this->request->data['id'];
            $this->Post->save($this->request->data);
        }else {
            // 更新
            $this->Post->save($this->request->data);
            $post_id = $this->Post->getLastInsertID();
            for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                if (!$this->Image->save($this->request->data['Image'][$i])) {
                    return $this->render('form');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

付け加えると、以下の動作を望んでいます。
・ファイルは最低１つ必要
・指定された場合のファイルサイズは2M以下
・JPEG, GIF, PNGを選択可能。

上記のようにしたいのですが
実際は４つのファイル全てを選択しないと次の画面に進めない状況です。
またwordファイルをアップロードしても次に進めてしまいます。
どこが間違っているのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/129200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 実際は４つのファイル全てを選択しないと次の画面に進めない状況です。

`images.image`がNOT NULLですので、おそらくフォームに`required`属性がついています。

```
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Post.Image.0.image', ['required' => false]); ?>
```

として、requiredを外してください。

> またwordファイルをアップロードしても次に進めてしまいます。

Controllerの処理で、`save`がエラーだった場合の分岐がないので、validationエラーが補足できていません。また、`save`のかわりに`saveAssociated`を使用するとアソシエーションを含めた保存ができますのでこちらを使用します。

```
if ($this->Post->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
    // 成功時の処理を書く
    $this->Flash->success('記事を保存しました。');

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'done']); // 保存完了後の飛び先を指定
}
// 失敗時の処理
$this->Flash->error('記事の保存に失敗しました。');
```

他に気になるところとして done アクションに保存処理を記述していますが、フォームを表示するアクションで保存処理を行い、完了画面であるdoneへはリダイレクトで飛ばしたほうがよいです。（そうしないとエラー時にエラーメッセージをフォームに戻せないので。

また、保存処理を追加時と更新時で処理を分けて書いていますが、今の仕様であれば不要です。
Controllerのアクションはざっくりと以下のようになります。

```
public function form($id) // フォームの表示アクション
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // POST時
        $this->request->data('Post.user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));
        if ($this->Post->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            // 成功時の処理を書く
            $this->Flash->success('記事を保存しました。');

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'done']);
        }
        // 失敗時の処理
        $this->Flash->error('記事の保存に失敗しました。');
    } elseif (!empty($id)) {
       // GETかつ編集（id指定）時
       // 既存データを取得
       $data = $this->Post->find('first', ['conditions' => ['Post.id' => $id]]);
       $this->request->data = $data;
    }
}
```

また、アップロードされたファイルの処理については、ImageモデルのbeforeSaveで処理するよう書きますが、Upload系のプラグイン（[cakephp-upload](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-upload/tree/2.x)等）を導入したほうがよいでしょう。